# Cart-Pole Python Performance Comparison

Tags: python-3.x, julia

I am comparing a cart and pole simulation with python 3.7 and Julia 1.2. In python the simulation is written as a class object as seen below, and in Julia is is just a function. I am getting a consistent 0.2 seconds time to solve using Julia which is much slower than python. I do not understand Julia well enough to understand why. My guess is it has something to do with compiling or the way the loop is set up.

```
import math
import random
from collections import namedtuple

RAD_PER_DEG = 0.0174533
DEG_PER_RAD = 57.2958

State = namedtuple('State', 'x x_dot theta theta_dot')

class CartPole:
    """ Model for the dynamics of an inverted pendulum
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.gravity   = 9.8
        self.masscart  = 1.0
        self.masspole  = 0.1
        self.length    = 0.5   # actually half the pole's length
        self.force_mag = 10.0
        self.tau       = 0.02  # seconds between state updates

        self.x         = 0
        self.x_dot     = 0
        self.theta     = 0
        self.theta_dot = 0

    @property
    def state(self):
        return State(self.x, self.x_dot, self.theta, self.theta_dot)

    def reset(self, x=0, x_dot=0, theta=0, theta_dot=0):
        """ Reset the model of a cartpole system to it's initial conditions
        "   theta is in radians
        """
        self.x         = x
        self.x_dot     = x_dot
        self.theta     = theta
        self.theta_dot = theta_dot

    def step(self, action):
        """ Move the state of the cartpole simulation forward one time unit
        """
        total_mass      = self.masspole + self.masscart
        pole_masslength = self.masspole * self.length

        force           = self.force_mag if action else -self.force_mag
        costheta        = math.cos(self.theta)
        sintheta        = math.sin(self.theta)

        temp = (force + pole_masslength * self.theta_dot ** 2 * sintheta) / total_mass

        # theta acceleration
        theta_dotdot = (
            (self.gravity * sintheta - costheta * temp)
            / (self.length *
               (4.0/3.0 - self.masspole * costheta * costheta /
                total_mass)))

        # x acceleration
        x_dotdot = temp - pole_masslength * theta_dotdot * costheta / total_mass

        self.x         += self.tau * self.x_dot
        self.x_dot     += self.tau * x_dotdot
        self.theta     += self.tau * self.theta_dot
        self.theta_dot += self.tau * theta_dotdot

        return self.state
```

To run the simulation the following code was used

```
from cartpole import CartPole
import time
cp = CartPole()
start = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
      cp.step(True)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

The Julia code is

```
function cartpole(state, action)
"""Cart and Pole simulation in discrete time
Inputs: cartpole( state, action )
state: 1X4 array [cart_position, cart_velocity, pole_angle, pole_velocity]
action: Boolean True or False where true is a positive force and False is a negative force
"""

gravity   = 9.8
masscart  = 1.0
masspole  = 0.1
l    = 0.5   # actually half the pole's length
force_mag = 10.0
tau       = 0.02  # seconds between state updates

# x         = 0
# x_dot     = 0
# theta     = 0
# theta_dot = 0

x         = state[1]
x_dot     = state[2]
theta     = state[3]
theta_dot = state[4]


total_mass = masspole + masscart
pole_massl = masspole * l

if action == 0
 force = force_mag
else
 force = -force_mag
end

costheta = cos(theta)
sintheta = sin(theta)

temp = (force + pole_massl * theta_dot^2 * sintheta) / total_mass

# theta acceleration
theta_dotdot = (gravity * sintheta - costheta * temp)/ (l *(4.0/3.0 - masspole * costheta * costheta / total_mass))

# x acceleration
x_dotdot = temp - pole_massl * theta_dotdot * costheta / total_mass

x         += tau * x_dot
x_dot     += tau * x_dotdot
theta     += tau * theta_dot
theta_dot += tau * theta_dotdot

new_state = [x x_dot theta theta_dot]

return new_state

end
```

The run code is

```
@time include("cartpole.jl")


function run_sim()
"""Runs the cartpole simulation
No inputs or ouputs
Use with @time run_sim() for timing puposes.
"""
 state = [0 0 0 0]
 for i = 1:100000
  state = cartpole( state, 0)
  #print(state)
  #print("\n")
end
end

@time run_sim()
```

Comment: When I run your julia code I get timings of `0.171631 seconds` on the first run (which includes compile time) and then the second time I run the code I get `0.021331 seconds` (ie. without compilation time). By contrast, when I run your python code (admittedly on python 3.6) I get 0.278 seconds. As mentioned though, there are many further performance optimizations available to you.

Answer (score 10):

Your Python version takes 0.21s on my laptop. Here are timing results for the original Julia version on the same system:

```
julia> @time run_sim()
  0.222335 seconds (654.98 k allocations: 38.342 MiB)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.019425 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 10.681 MiB, 37.52% gc time)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.010103 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 10.681 MiB)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.012553 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 10.681 MiB)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.011470 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 10.681 MiB)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.025003 seconds (100.00 k allocations: 10.681 MiB, 52.82% gc time)
```

The first run includes JIT compilation and takes ~0.2s whereas after that each run takes 10-20ms. That breaks down into ~10ms of actual compute time and ~10s of garbage collection time triggered every four calls or so. That means that Julia is about 10-20x faster than Python, excluding JIT compilation time, which is not bad for a straight port.

Why not count JIT time when benchmarking? Because you don't actually care about how long it takes to run fast programs like benchmarks. You're timing small benchmark problems to extrapolate how long it it will take to run larger problems where speed really matters. JIT compilation time is proportional to the amount of *code* you're compiling not to problem size. So when solving larger problems that you actually care about, the JIT compilation will still only take 0.2s, which is a negligible fraction of execution time for large problems.

Now, let's see about making the Julia code even faster. This is actually very simple: use a tuple instead of a row vector for your state. So initialize the state as `state = (0, 0, 0, 0)` and then update the state similarly:

```
new_state = (x, x_dot, theta, theta_dot)
```

That's it, otherwise the code is identical. For this version the timings are:

```
julia> @time run_sim()
  0.132459 seconds (479.53 k allocations: 24.020 MiB)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.008218 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.007230 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.005379 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)

julia> @time run_sim()
  0.008773 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

The first run still includes JIT time. Subsequent runs are now 5-10ms, which is about 25-40x faster than the Python version. Note that there are almost no allocations—small, fixed numbers of allocations are just for return values and won't trigger GC if this is called from other code in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so I've just run your Python and Julia code, and I get different results: 1.41 s for 10m iterations for Julia, 25.5 seconds for 10m iterations for Python. Already, Julia is 18x faster!

I think perhaps the issue is that `@time` is not accurate when run in global scope - you need multi-second timings for it to be accurate enough. You can use the package `BenchmarkTools` to get accurate timings of small functions.

Comment: `@time` can have slight overhead in global scope, but the times involved are huge (1.41s is an eternity for a computer) and there's not that much overhead. The issue is that the first run include JIT. If you increase the number of iterations, the JIT time stays the same but the execution time will go up, of course. (That's why we don't count JIT in benchmarks.)

Answer (score 2):

Standard performance tips apply: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html
In particular, use dots to avoid allocations, and fuse loops. Also for this kind of small-array computations, consider using https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl which is much faster

Comment: Also don't time just once: do `@time` multiple times to amortize compilation time, or (even better) use BenchmarkTools. With StaticArrays and multiple `@time` I get 0.006s